# How to turn columns into rows without available library functions (Python)

Tags: python, sorting

So I have this, which only works when the number of columns (number of elements in my sublist) is equal to the number of rows I want to create.

```
list1 = [[2, 1, 2, 6],[1, 5, 4, 9],[4, 2, 3, 2],[1, 4, 5, 7]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    columns.append([row[i] for row in list1])
```

I tried this to make it universal, meaning it'll accept any combination of list length and sublist length (ex. [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]) but the error I got was that j wasn't defined.

```
for i,j in range(len(list1[i][j])):
    columns.append([row[i] for row in list1])
```

How can I change this to make it work?
My list has to be a NxM matrix, and I can't use any shortcuts like min, max, zip, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by that: _it didn't work ... (yet i was never defined and it still worked)_?

Comment: It worked for just the i, but when I added a j it didn't work.  I want to make it more universal, meaning that the code will accept any length list and sublist, that's why I was trying to reference to the number of items in the sublist with the j, so I'm asking for a way around this.

Comment: Neither of your code snippets work. You have undefined `i`, `columns` and for the second snippet variable `j` is added to undefined.

Comment: Well, that's the problem... it does work with just the i. In my variable table the list 'columns' fills up correctly. So do you know how I can define it properly?

Comment: Ok I copied it incorrectly, now it is how I have it in my code, which works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work. The main ideas are to create an empty over-all result list and empty sub-lists at the proper time and append to them. Note that the input matrix has size `m x n`, `m` rows and `n` columns, which is the standard way to state matrix size. The result has size `n x m`. You may swap the `m` and `n` names to correspond with your lessons or book, if you like.

```
m, n = len(list1), len(list1[0])
result = []
for col in range(n):
    result.append([])
    for row in range(m):
        result[col].append(list1[row][col])
```

If you do not like the temporarily-empty lists or appends, an alternative approach that is often used in languages other than Python is to create a temporary result matrix of the proper size then fill in the correct entries, like this:

```
m, n = len(list1), len(list1[0])
result = [[None] * m for col in range(n)]
for col in range(n):
    for row in range(m):
        result[col][row] = list1[row][col]
```

Also, there is also the briefer but harder-to-understand list comprehension:

```
[[list1[row][col] for row in range(len(list1))] for col in range(len(list1[0]))]
```

All that said, the better way in Python is

```
result = list(map(list, (zip(*list1))))
```

(That last includes a correction by @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ.)

Comment: `list(map(list, (zip(*l))))`, if you want the inner items to be lists too.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Yes, you are right, my `zip`ped version makes the inner items to be tuples. Shall I correct my answer or let people see your correction?

Comment: Wow, you guys really like to pat each other on the back. Listen, I understand zip is easier, I mentioned it in my question. Do you think I would hurt myself for fun like that? (don't answer that).

Comment: @SylviaH: I am working on improving my politeness while being honest, but I sometimes overshoot one direction or the other. This site is intended to keep good questions and answers for future reference, so I thought it would be good to make the `zip` solution clear to other readers, even if you already know that solution. I got that solution wrong the first time, showing that it is not exactly obvious.

Comment: I was a bit snappy because I was upset by my question being downvoted. I thought that it was a genuinely good question considering I couldn't not find any others that did not reference 'zip'. In retrospect, I realise it took me a couple of edits to make clear what I was asking. Also, it may seem like backwards to do all that work when it can be done in one line. I guess my teacher was forcing us to think a little more.